# Plotting two principal component score vectors, using a different color to indicate three unique classes

Tags: r, plot, pca

After generating a simulated data set with 20 observations in each of three classes (i.e., 60 observations total), and 50 variables, I need to plot the first two principal component score vectors, using a different color to indicate the three unique classes.

I believe I can create the simulated data set (please verify), but I am having issues figuring out how to color the classes and plot. I need to make sure the three classes appear separated in the plot (or else I need to re-run the simulated data).

```
#for the response variable y (60 values - 3 classes 1,2,3  - 20 observations per class)
y <- rep(c(1,2,3),20)

#matrix of 50 variables i.e. 50 columns and 60 rows i.e. 60x50 dimensions (=3000 table cells)   
x <- matrix( rnorm(3000), ncol=50)

xymatrix <- cbind(y,x)
dim(x)
[1] 60 50
dim(xymatrix)
[1] 60 51
pca=prcomp(xymatrix, scale=TRUE)
```

How should I correctly plot and color this principal component analysis as noted above? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the code that creates the current plot you have?

Comment: @BLT This in no way needs to be a biplot (there might be a better way to plot it), but below is the code I tried:                                                     `biplot(pca, scale=0, col=c("orange", "red", "blue"))`

Comment: Does this work with your real data? http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_pca

Comment: @BLT I can get the first code below to plot, but I am not sure how to have the three classes colored differently (i.e., all dots are orange)    `autoplot(pca, colour = "orange")`  This code does not work: `autoplot(pca, colour = c("orange", "red", "blue"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `ggparcoord` in `Gally` package would help you.

```
library(GGally)
y <- rep(c(1,2,3), 20)

# matrix of 50 variables i.e. 50 columns and 60 rows 
# i.e. 60x50 dimensions (=3000 table cells)   
x <- matrix(rnorm(3000), ncol=50)

xymatrix <- cbind(y,x)
pca <- prcomp(xymatrix, scale=TRUE)

# Principal components score and group label 'y'
pc_label <- data.frame(pca$x, y=as.factor(y))

# Plot the first two principal component scores of each samples
ggparcoord(data=pc_label, columns=1:2, groupColumn=ncol(pc_label))
```

However, I think it makes more sense to do PCA on `x` rather than `xymatrix` that includes the target `y`. So the following codes should be more appropriate in your case.

```
pca <- prcomp(x, scale=TRUE)

pc_label <- data.frame(pca$x, y=as.factor(y))

ggparcoord(data=pc_label, columns=1:2, groupColumn=ncol(pc_label))
```

---

If you want a scatter plot of first two principal component scores, you can do it using `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=pc_label) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, colour=y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution, to show how simply this can be done. First do the PCA on the `x` matrix only and from the resulting object get a matrix of the transformed variables which we'll call `PCs`.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(3000), ncol=50)
pca <- prcomp(x, scale=TRUE)
PCs <- as.matrix(pca$x)
```

Now we can make vector of colour names based on your `y` for the labels.

```
col.labs <- rep(c("Green", "Blue", "Red"), 20)
```

Now just plot as a scatter, passing the colour vector to `col`.

```
plot(PCs[, 1], PCs[, 2], col=col.labs, pch=19, xlab = "Scores on PC1", ylab="Scores on PC2")
```

[image]